# HttpServletRequest can not get data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot

Request URL:`http://localhost:8080/deduct/migration/export?fromId=872`

java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void export(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam(value="fromId") String from ) throws IOException {
  String fromId=request.getParameter("fromId");//fromId=null
  System.out.println(from);//from=872
}
```

Why 'request.getParameter (fromId)' is null?

Please help me, grateful!

I added "", but forgot to fill out the problem, sorry

Comment: you should use the parameter name not the value. `String fromId=request.getParameter("fromId")`

Comment: Read the line... Small hint there are no `"` around `fromId`.

Comment: you want to get fromId value 872 right? i think you got it using @RequestParam and 'from' string is what you looking for.

Comment: I added "", but forgot to fill out the problem, sorry

Comment: `from` is enough to hold value 872. I don't know why you have to use `HttpServletRequest`? Are you message your import statement is correct? `import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;`

Comment: I confirm that I have imported javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest